# Managing pgfplot labels

Tags: pgfplots, graphics, labels

I am working with Pgfplot to plot some graphics, and I am having some trouble managing its labels. Specifically, I would like to know how to remove an automatically generated label. Let's take a look at the graphic generated.

[image: Graphic]

Now, let's take a look at the following TeX snippet.

```
...
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel={Year},
    ylabel={Cases per million},
    xmin=1980, xmax=2022,
    ymin=0, ymax=3300000,
    xtick={1980, 1983, 1986, 1989, 1992, 1995, 1998, 2001, 2004, 2007, 2010, 2013, 2016, 2019, 2022},
    xticklabels={1980, 1983, 1986, 1989, 1992, 1995, 1998, 2001, 2004, 2007, 2010, 2013, 2016, 2019, 2022},
    legend pos=north west,
    label style={font=\tiny},
    legend style={font=\tiny},
    tick label style={font=\tiny},
    width=10cm,
    height=6cm
    ]
...
```

The entire code can be seen at [here](https://www.latex4technics.com?note=zzvtdr).
I would like to know how to remove the 10^6 label placed at the left top of the graphic. It seems it was automatically generated by the pgfplot.

Thanks for your attention, and if anyone has any questions, please, let me know.

Comment: This is called "scientific notation" and there are several duplicates for that.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, thanks for the comment. I did not know the proper term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `scaled y ticks=false`, the y-axis tick labels will be `1 \cdot 10^6`, `2 \cdot 10^6`, and `3 \cdot 10^6`.

To configure the number format, you can add `/pgf/number format/...` options to `tick label style={...}`. For example,

```tex
tick label style={font=\tiny, /pgf/number format/fixed}
```

will change y-axis tick labels to `1,000,000`, `2,000,000`, and `3,000,000`.

For more info, you can check `pgfplots` package manual, sec. 4.15.3 "*Tick Scaling – Common Factors In Ticks*" and sec. 4.13 "*Number Formatting Options*".

```tex
\documentclass[notheorems]{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        %      title={Dengue reported cases from 1980 to 2022},
        scaled ticks=false,
        xlabel={Year},
        ylabel={Cases per million},
        xmin=1980, xmax=2022,
        ymin=0, ymax=3300000,
        xtick={1980, 1983, 1986, 1989, 1992, 1995, 1998, 2001, 2004, 2007, 2010, 2013, 2016, 2019, 2022},
        xticklabels={1980, 1983, 1986, 1989, 1992, 1995, 1998, 2001, 2004, 2007, 2010, 2013, 2016, 2019, 2022},
        legend pos=north west,
        label style={font=\tiny},
        legend style={font=\tiny},
        tick label style={font=\tiny, /pgf/number format/fixed},
        width=10cm,
        height=6cm
        ]
        \addplot[
          color=blue,
          mark=x,
          ]
          plot coordinates {
            (1980, 65523)
            (1981, 377916)
            (1982, 68892)
            (1983, 40544)
            (1984, 38904)
            (1985, 158193)
            (1986, 88093)
            (1987, 134013)
            (1988, 467386)
            (1989, 94179)
            (1990, 157662)
            (1991, 254749)
            (1992, 112567)
            (1993, 98598)
            (1994, 232051)
            (1995, 331417)
            (1996, 287519)
            (1997, 410392)
            (1998, 729425)
            (1999, 317158)
            (2000, 394857)
            (2001, 636977)
            (2002, 1001073)
            (2003, 506726)
            (2004, 257251)
            (2005, 413122)
            (2006, 537412)
            (2007, 874750)
            (2008, 884334)
            (2009, 1099742)
            (2010, 1648569)
            (2011, 1073990)
            (2012, 1164366)
            (2013, 2384803)
            (2014, 1184045)
            (2015, 2416018)
            (2016, 2175409)
            (2017, 579027)
            (2018, 561689)
            (2019, 3190778)
            (2020, 2326115)
            (2021, 1254648)
            (2022, 211882)
          };
        \addlegendentry{International}

        \addplot[
          color=red,
          mark=x,
          ]
          plot coordinates {
            (1980, 9003)
            (1981, 10861)
            (1982, 19034)
            (1983, 12925)
            (1984, 7560)
            (1985, 82273)
            (1986, 55248)
            (1987, 108955)
            (1988, 441382)
            (1989, 65803)
            (1990, 114431)
            (1991, 217077)
            (1992, 72319)
            (1993, 41250)
            (1994, 134342)
            (1995, 211396)
            (1996, 226960)
            (1997, 307625)
            (1998, 632804)
            (1999, 252762)
            (2000, 326846)
            (2001, 572876)
            (2002, 903891)
            (2003, 434264)
            (2004, 193334)
            (2005, 294943)
            (2006, 432661)
            (2007, 724077)
            (2008, 810134)
            (2009, 756755)
            (2010, 1317801)
            (2011, 923793)
            (2012, 843840)
            (2013, 1857228)
            (2014, 857983)
            (2015, 1978921)
            (2016, 1860466)
            (2017, 385076)
            (2018, 382243)
            (2019, 2453060)
            (2020, 2021272)
            (2021, 1134555)
            (2022, 199319)
          };
        \addlegendentry{South america}

        \addplot[
          color=yellow,
          mark=x,
          ]
          plot coordinates {
            (1980, 0)
            (1981, 0)
            (1982, 12000)
            (1983, 0)
            (1984, 0)
            (1985, 0)
            (1986, 47367)
            (1987, 89393)
            (1988, 190)
            (1989, 5334)
            (1990, 40642)
            (1991, 97209)
            (1992, 3501)
            (1993, 6915)
            (1994, 54453)
            (1995, 124775)
            (1996, 175749)
            (1997, 254074)
            (1998, 535283)
            (1999, 204131)
            (2000, 231412)
            (2001, 412388)
            (2002, 778037)
            (2003, 341189)
            (2004, 112851)
            (2005, 203356)
            (2006, 345922)
            (2007, 558413)
            (2008, 724427)
            (2009, 520660)
            (2010, 994158)
            (2011, 753487)
            (2012, 597450)
            (2013, 1473645)
            (2014, 591080)
            (2015, 1649008)
            (2016, 1500535)
            (2017, 252054)
            (2018, 265934)
            (2019, 2248570)
            (2020, 1467142)
            (2021, 975474)
            (2022, 167602)
          };
        \addlegendentry{Brazil}
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    %  \caption{Dengue reported cases from 1980 to 2022~\myfootcite{PAHODengueData2022}.}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note it's recommended to provide the complete example *directly* to this site, so the Q&A could be self-contained even if the link is dead.

Comment: Very thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for.